Ambiguous functioning of i2c register reading
I use the library “golang.org/x/exp/io/i2c” to handle a certain module (AS3935). The module provides 9 registers with the ability to read and write values to them, they are addressed from 0x00 to 0x08. When the ReadReg function is called (its description is: ReadReg is similar to Read but it reads from a register.), no matter which address byte I specify as the first parameter, the first register is always returned. Only after the buffer is increased I can see that the values of subsequent registers are in the next fields of the buffer. What is the register parameter used for then?
This is how the helper functions look like, which I will use to write and read values:
type module struct {
    // I want to read/write only one byte per call so the buffers size is 1.
    BufferRead  []uint8
    BufferWrite []uint8
    
    // ... other not relevent fields
}


// Read a value from the register specified by the offset parameter.
func (m *module) RegRead(offset uint8) (uint8, error) {
    err := m.Device.ReadReg(offset, m.BufferRead)
    if err != nil {
        return 0x00, err
    }

    return m.BufferRead[0], nil
}

// Write a value byte parameter to the register specified by the offset parameter.
func (m *module) RegWrite(offset, value uint8) error {
    m.BufferWrite[0] = value

    err := m.Device.WriteReg(offset, m.BufferWrite)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}


Have seen comments (eg1, eg2) that there are some issues with this IC's I2C support, so might be worth testing with i2cdump or similar before assuming it's your code. Note that golang.org/x/exp/io/i2c is depreciated, so periph.io is probably a better option (if that's too heavy I use a cut down version).

I was not aware of this alternative library, thanks for the info. Indeed, I see that there are problems with I2c on this chip. I'll try to look into it and solve the problem software-wise. Thanks for the info, I'll keep you posted on the results.

Are you running this on Linux? If so, use in-kernel driver: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/proximity/as3935.c.
